# How to do Topological Sort (Dependency Resolution) with Java

Tags: java, graph, guava, directed-graph, jgrapht

**Description**

The purpose of the question is to implement an interface that will order a list of tasks according to the information about their dependencies. For example, if task A has a dependency on tasks B and C, this means that to start working on task A, tasks B and C have to be completed first. As I think it should be like directed graph structure.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * The task class represents a certain activities that must be done as the part of the project planning
 */
class Task {

    /**
     * Unique name of the activity
     */
    private String name;

    /**
     * A list of names of the activities that must be completed in order to be able to start the current activity
     */
    private List<String> predecessors;

    public Task(String name, List<String> predecessors) {
        this.name = name;
        this.predecessors = predecessors;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<String> getPredecessors() {
        return predecessors;
    }
}
```

The interface shall take a list of tasks (defined in any order) as the input parameter and output a list of tasks sorted in the order they may be executed.

```
/**
 * A scheduler interface is intended to process a random list of tasks with the information of their predecessors
 * and return a list of the same tasks but in order they may be executed according to their dependencies
 */
interface IScheduler {
    public List<Task> schedule(List<Task> tasks);
}
```

The following code provides an example of how the interface can be used.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**
         * The following is the example of how the scheduler may be used
         */
        List<Task> tasks = Arrays.asList(
            new Task("E", Arrays.asList("B")),
            new Task("D", Arrays.asList("A", "B")),
            new Task("A", Arrays.asList()),
            new Task("B", Arrays.asList("A")),
            new Task("C", Arrays.asList("D", "B")),
            new Task("F", Arrays.asList("E"))
        );

        IScheduler scheduler = /* implementation here*/;
        List<Task> sortedTasks = scheduler.schedule(tasks);
        for (Task t: sortedTasks) {
            System.out.println(t.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**

How can I implement interface to sort tasks ? Am I need to use something like `JGraphT` or `Guava Graph` or there is some easy way ?

Comment: Take a look on [JGraphT TopologicalOrderIterator](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/traverse/TopologicalOrderIterator.html)

Comment: Yes, That's work for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) for such dependency resolution problem.
Quoting from the above link

> For instance, the vertices of the graph may represent tasks to be performed, and the edges may represent constraints that one task must be performed before another; in this application, a topological ordering is just a valid sequence for the tasks. A topological ordering is possible if and only if the graph has no directed cycles, that is, if it is a directed acyclic graph (DAG)

[JGraphT](https://jgrapht.org/) provides [`DirectedAcyclicGraph`](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc-1.0.0/org/jgrapht/experimental/dag/DirectedAcyclicGraph.html) and [`TopologicalOrderIterator`](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc-1.0.0/org/jgrapht/traverse/TopologicalOrderIterator.html) which can solve our problem easily.

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.jgrapht.Graph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DirectedAcyclicGraph;
import org.jgrapht.traverse.TopologicalOrderIterator;

public class TopologicalSortExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // DirectAcyclicGraph to prevent circular dependency
        Graph<Task, DefaultEdge> directedGraph = new DirectedAcyclicGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
        List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
        tasks.add(new Task("E", Arrays.asList("B")));
        tasks.add(new Task("D", Arrays.asList("A", "B")));
        tasks.add(new Task("A", Arrays.asList()));
        tasks.add(new Task("B", Arrays.asList("A")));
        tasks.add(new Task("C", Arrays.asList("D", "B")));
        tasks.add(new Task("F", Arrays.asList("E")));
        Map<String, Task> taskNameToTaskMap = tasks.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(task -> task.getName(), task -> task));
        for (Task task : tasks) {
            directedGraph.addVertex(task);
            for (String predecessor : task.getPredecessors()) {
                Task predecessorTask = taskNameToTaskMap.get(predecessor);
                directedGraph.addVertex(predecessorTask);
                directedGraph.addEdge(predecessorTask, task);
            }
        }
        TopologicalOrderIterator<Task, DefaultEdge> moreDependencyFirstIterator = new TopologicalOrderIterator<>(
                directedGraph);
        moreDependencyFirstIterator.forEachRemaining(task -> System.out.println(task.getName()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

From what I can understand, your problem can be solved using [observer pattern](https://stackabuse.com/behavioral-design-patterns-in-java/#observer)

> The Observer pattern is used to monitor the state of a certain object, often in a group or one-to-many relationship. In such cases, most of the time, the changed state of a single object can affect the state of the rest, so there must be a system to note the change and alert the other objects.

so you can perform or start a certain task when you are alerted on change of state of that object.